# Assigning output of table function in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector like this:

```
    agg$RNAtype
 [1] "HnRn" "HyRy" "HnRn" "HyRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRy" "HnRn" "HnRy"
[12] "HnRn"
```

And when I want to calculate the number of occurrence of each type (ie "HnRn","HyRn","HnRy","HyRy") I can use table(agg$RNAtype) which gives :

```
 > table(agg$RNAtype)

HnRn HnRy HyRn HyRy 
   8    2    1    1
```

But I want to do it in a way which will store the values in a vector or variables. ie I want to make variables(for example) HnRn which will store the value 8.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values would already be in a vector if you just saved the result

```
tt <- table(agg$RNAtype)
tt["HnRn"]
# HnRn 
#    8
```

Basically you have a named vector. The name of the vector will typically be drawn above the value, but you can use it like any other numerical value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I actually want to use the values corresponding to HnRn etc to make a contingency table. So, I am trying to make a variable which will store 8 only. Is it possible?

Comment: Technically you can, but I certainly don't recommend it. I don't understand why you can't use the named vector to make your contingency table. Or you could even use `with(as.list(tt), HnRn+HnRy)` to pretend they are variable names for the duration of the `with()` command. Otherwise you can do `invisible(mapply(assign, names(tt), tt, MoreArgs=list(globalenv())))` to make them proper variables in the global environment. But really, that just gets messy quickly.